# Always return numbers of values inside of array Javascript,

Tags: javascript, json, vue-chartjs

Good day,

I have a JSON data like this,

```
const incidents = [
   {
      "id": 3,
      "fullName": "Fatima Elaran",
      "address": "San Marcos, Calumpit, Bulacan",
   },
   {
      "id": 4,
      "fullName": "Leni Elaran",
      "address": "San Marcos, Calumpit, Bulacan",
   }
]
```

I aggregate the totals by address, by doing this:

```
      const count = incidents.reduce((a, c) => {
        a[c.address] = (a[c.address] || 0) + 1;
        return a;
      }, {});
```

which sets `count` to:

```
{ San Marcos, Calumpit, Bulacan: 2 }
```

So now, I update my chart to show this aggregated data:

```
      Object.keys(count).forEach(key => {
        this.barChart.labels.push(key);
      });
      Object.values(count).forEach(data => {
        this.barChart.data.push(data);
      });
```

But `barChart.data` ends with this data: `[2, "San Marcos, Calumpit, Bulacan"]`

I want it to have just this: `["San Marcos, Calumpit, Bulacan"]`

Comment: What version of *chart.js* are you using? I do not see an API [here](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/usage.html) that has `barChart.data` which is of type array.

Comment: [vue-chart](https://github.com/hchstera/vue-charts) @FrankFajardo

Comment: I updated your question to make it clearer. Looking at your code, this loop: `Object.values(count).forEach(data => { this.barChart.data.push(data); })` should really be setting `barChart.data` to `[2]`.

Comment: `Object.values(count).forEach(data => {
    this.barChart.data.push(data);
});`

correctly adds the value 2 to this.barChart.data. If you are getting the output as you mentioned then there is some other wrong thing you might be doing. Can you check all the places you are modifying this.barChart.data?